# Converting Lead to a specific Account type

Tags: lead-conversion

On converting leads I want to be able to specify which Account type (not record type) will be created.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: during a lead conversion the account is not yet created and trying to set an account type for a yet created account is not possible, One way I can think is on successful lead conversion update the account type = 'something' which makes it look as if the record is created with Account type = 'something'

Comment: @rao answered !Please see m answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
  trigger test on Lead (before update) { 
    If ( Lead.IsConverted && !trigger.oldmap.get(lead.id).IsConverted){//This identifies the conversion process
          //Execute your logic 
      }
```

Follow the above to identify conversion process and set the record type or type

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution which allow the user to decide which type will be set because there is no specific logic I can program

Comment: you need vf then